# Removing Angular secondary outlet route from browser history

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I use the following code (exactly like the example at https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets) to show a popup menu when the user clicks on his account in the header:

`<a role="button" [routerLink]="[{outlets: {popup: ['account']}}]"></a>`

My problem is that every click adds the item to the browser history, once to show and once to hide. I tried using `{skipLocationChange: true}` but then this causes a complete browser refresh for some reason.